# How to update the window during a callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, tkinter

When a Tkinter button is clicked and the command is run, the GUI seems frozen until the command returns.

Example, the counter wont update until after 2 seconds:

```python
import tkinter as tk
import time

class Window():

    def __init__(self):
        self.clicks = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.button_text = tk.StringVar(value="Click " + str(self.clicks))
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, textvariable=self.button_text,
                                command=self.click)
        self.button.pack()

    def click(self):
        self.clicks += 1
        self.button_text.set("Click " + str(self.clicks))
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window().root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way to allow the window to be updated during a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the button's [`update_idletasks`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) method:

```
def click(self):
    self.clicks += 1
    self.button_text.set("Click " + str(self.clicks))
    ##################################
    self.button.update_idletasks()
    ##################################
    time.sleep(2)
```

Adding that line to `click` will cause the button's text to update immediately.

Comment: The sleep will cause your GUI to sleep no matter what tricks you try. You should never call sleep in the main thread of a GUI. Also, as a rule of thumb you should always use `update_idletasks` instead of `update` unless you absolutely have to use `update`.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I agree to both of your points.  The second I will implement right now.  However, regarding the first, I don't think the OP is actually sleeping for no reason.  Instead, I think he used `time.sleep` to represent a time-consuming operation.

Answer (score 0):

The sleep is blocking the gui's event loop

Comment: I realise that, is there any way to update it during the calback? I'd like to update a status bar to "Working...", then do some work (which might take a while), then update it to "Done".

Comment: You have to do the work that takes time in a sepearate thread