# Python+tkinter: Text widget doesn't change text immidiately

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tk.Text() widget and a button. When the button is clicked, I want to change the text in the Text widget, then conduct a lengthy job. Here is code snippet from the button command function:

```
price_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
price_text.insert(tk.END, 'PLEASE WAIT..')  
result = self.the_lengthy_job()
```

However, the 'PLEASE WAIT..' message just won't show up until self.the_length_job() returns. Is it possible to get it show before the_length_job() starts?

---EDIT---
Here is more code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pandas_datareader as web

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("800x480")
        self.price_text = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.price_text.grid(row=0, column=0, )

        tk.Button(self.root, text="Get", command=self.do_get).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def do_get(self):
        self.price_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        self.price_text.insert(tk.END, "PLEASE WAIT..")
        result = self.lengthy_job()

    def lengthy_job(self):
        tickers = ["GOOG", "AAPL", "MSFT", "IBM", "F", "AMZN", "NVDA", "NFLX", "DISH", "BABA", "JD", "SHOP", "PDD", "CSCO", "AMD", "INTC", "TXN", "MU", "QCOM"]
        return web.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start="2020-1-1", end="2020-1-31")

GUI()
```

In this example, "PLEASE WAIT.." only shows up after lengthy_job() is done.

Comment: Show us some more code please

Comment: You need to call `self.root.update()` right after inserting the text into the text widget.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin thanks for your advice. Also noted that `self.price_text.update()` can do the same job. If you put it into answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Please don't remove the full code from your question; it's important to understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the window is not being updated after the text is inserted. This is because events are only processed *after* a callback returns.

To force the window to process the events *before* the callback returns, you can call `self.root.update_idletasks()` (at CoolCloud's suggestion, you shouldn't use `update()` unless it's absolutely necessary). Here is what the `do_get()` should look like:

```py
def do_get(self):
    self.price_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    self.price_text.insert(tk.END, "PLEASE WAIT..")
    self.root.update_idletasks() # Update the window here
    result = self.lengthy_job()
```

Comment: That is true, but if that is the case, they might be facing a bigger problem of _why_ the events are not being processed, that too inside a button callback

Comment: @CoolCloud True; however, as I don't know why, I can't post it in the answer. It may even be a Tcl-level thing, which the OP probably can't fix themselves, at least not using Python code. If I ever find out, I'll put it here. Something to note: `update()` also needs to be called when using `Button.bind("<Button-1>")`.

Comment: Are you sure? I have never faced such a problem

Comment: @CoolCloud I know `update()` needs to be called when using `bind("<Button-1>"` _because I tested it_; I used `bind()` instead of `command=`, and the text was only inserted after `lengthy_job()` returned. I try not to state facts without testing them first, especially on Stack Overflow :-). Did you test the OP's code? Did it not have the same problem for you?

Comment: No I did not even get the code, infact I just saw the code been removed, right now.

Comment: @CoolCloud Hopefully someone will edit it and return the code; in the meantime, however, you can look in the question's [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70609391/revisions) to see it.

Comment: Ah yes, well then you may want to explain that events gets processed only after a callback returns, because that is the case here. And also I've heard to always use `update_idletasks()` instead of `update()` unless its really necessary.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks for the advice, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Oh and also, it isn't not really my suggestion, I follow Bryan's comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20820878/13382000) answer. AFAIK, `update()` does `update_idletasks()` and more.